# Can I cast the output of a function with typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have this code:

```
.success((data: any[], status, headers, config) => {
    self.userTests.data = data;
    self.userTests.dataMap = _.reduce(data, function (rv, v) {
        rv[v.userTestId] = v;
        return rv;
    }, {});
})
```

The interface for dataMap is IUserTestDataMap and the output of the _.reduce is giving me the correct data. However Typescript complains with an error:

```
Error   9   Cannot convert '{}' to 'IUserTestDataMap':
    Index signatures of types '{}' and 'IUserTestDataMap' are incompatible.
```

Is there a way I can cast the data with Typescript so that it accepts the output from the _.reduce function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Casting can be done like this:

```
<IUserTestDataMap>{}
```

This casting operator does nothing other than tell the compiler "trust me, this object should be treated in the following as if it was of the specified type".

```
interface Foo {
    id: number;
}

var x : Foo;
x = {}; // error
x = <Foo>{}; // okay

var y = {};
x = <Foo>y; // okay
```